# filter() a data frame by whether a value is in the first 12 rows of a column on another frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm working with an index of all the snapchats a friend has sent within the last month. It's in a frame `df` and the relevant attributes are `to` and `time`. I'd like to isolate the instances that are "to" any of the 12 most frequent names in `to`. I have a data frame `summary` with each unique value of `to` and their frequencies. `summary` is  defined by:

```
> summary <- arrange(count(df, to), desc(n))
```

I've tried using filter() to compare values of `df$to` to `head(summary$to, 12)`

```
> top12 <- filter(df, to == head(summary$to, 12))
```

which gave me the error

```
Warning message:
In to == head(summary$to, 12) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

and a very strange data frame for `top12` that has a seemingly random selection of instances from each `to` with fewer rows than there are instances of each of the top 5 `to` values. I can use a vector with the names manually entered and get exactly what I should, but I want a scalable solution so I can easily expand or contract the range included and easily update when I add data from future months. Because the vector worked, I tried converting `head(summary$to, 12)` to a vector but got the same error.

```
> top12 <- filter(df, to == c("name 1","name 2", ... "name 12"))
> top12 <- filter(df, to == as.vector(head(summary$to, 12)))
Warning message:
In to == as.vector(head(summary$to, 12)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

What am I doing wrong? Any more concise ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
top12 <- filter(df, to %in% summary$to[1:12])
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but do you know why I was getting that error before?

Comment: `to == head(summary$to, 12)` basically means "keep the values of `to` that **equal** the first 12 values in `summary$to`. What you really wanted was "keep the values of `to` that **are in** the first 12 values in `summary$to`. Probably would have worked if you used `%in%` instead of `==`.